Unable to apply my own modifications to templates/ for the apache superset Helm chart
I'm using superset's latest version currently. (version: 0.12.9)
I have added my own secret model to templates/ folder so that it gets generated automatically using helm upgrade.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ template "superset.fullname" . }}-config-oci
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "superset.fullname" . }}
    chart: {{ template "superset.chart" . }}
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
type: Opaque
stringData:
  {{- if .Values.extraSecretsOci }}
  {{- range $path, $config := .Values.**extraSecretsOci** }}
  {{ $path }}: |
    {{- tpl $config $ | nindent 4 -}}
  {{- end -}}
  {{- end -}}

I have added its needed volumes and volumemounts sections to templates/deployment.yaml so that the secret gets mounted to the superset pod as a volume.
volumeMounts:
            - name: superset-config
              mountPath: {{ .Values.configMountPath | quote }}
              readOnly: true
            {{- if .Values.extraConfigs }}
            - name: superset-extra-config
              mountPath: {{ .Values.extraConfigMountPath | quote }}
              readOnly: true
            {{- end }}
            - name: superset-config-oci
              mountPath: {{ .Values.configMountPathOci | quote }}
              readOnly: true
volumes:
        - name: superset-config
          secret:
            secretName: {{ tpl .Values.configFromSecret . }}
        {{- if .Values.extraConfigs }}
        - name: superset-extra-config
          configMap:
            name: {{ template "superset.fullname" . }}-extra-config
        {{- end }}
        - name: superset-config-oci
          secret:
            secretName: {{ tpl .Values.configFromSecretOci . }}
        {{- with .Values.extraVolumes }}
          {{- tpl (toYaml .) $ | nindent 8 -}}
        {{- end }}

And finally, I have given the needed values to my modified-values.yaml file:
extraSecretsOci:
  user_oci.pem: "private_key file"
  config: "config file"

configMountPathOci: "/root/.oci"

configFromSecretOci: superset-config-oci

When I upgrade the helm chart, the secret doesn't get created and there is no sign of application of my modifications.
Expected behaviour:
The creation of superset-config-oci containing two secret values config and oci_user.pem.
The mounting of the two values inside the superset container on the location /root/.oci.
NAME                             TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-69k9j              kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      49d
sh.helm.release.v1.superset.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      49m
sh.helm.release.v1.superset.v2   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      44m
sh.helm.release.v1.superset.v3   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      17m
superset-config                  Opaque                                3      49m
**superset-config-oci**          **Opaque**                            **2**  **17m**
superset-env                     Opaque                                12     49m
superset-postgresql              Opaque                                2      49m
superset-redis-token-pg69m       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      49m

Current behaviour:
None of the expected behaviour has happened.

What you tried running helm template to check if all the YAML resources are generated as expected?

@RuiJarimba Yes sure, only the helm yaml files that were created by default are generated, mine are not.

Updating
I have asked the superset community and they have given me three options to achieve what I wanted:

you could open a PR to add this functionality to the helm chart.
you could roll your own chart and add the superset chart as a subchart,
this would allow to you define any additional templates you’d need.
This would require a fair amount of set up, especially for a single
pvc template, but updating the superset subchart would be a simple
process.
fork the superset helm chart and add any functionality you’d
need. The downside is you’d have pull in any updates manually.

I have chosen to go with the second option. I've made the needed set up and integrated the exact configuration I have shown in the original post, it's now  working fine!
